# How to get value

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem and a code like this.

```
{"resultcode":"0","message":"Success","description":[{"STORECODE":"F3YQ","STORENAME":"BUNGUR BESAR 30B","ADDRESS":"JL.BUNGUR BESAR NO.30BGUNUNG SAHARI SELATAN","PHONE":"021","POSTALCODE":"10610","OPHOURS":"EVERYDAY (07.00-22.00)","LATITUDE":"-6.1605556","LONGITUDE":"106.8391667","DCCODE":"G137","DCNAME":"JKT2"}]}
```

I was difficult to get the value. 
I need a value like this :

Success
F3YQ
10610
JKT2

Comment: It's json encoded data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite straight forward,

```
$a = json_decode($yourArr, true); // last parameter to convert it into array
echo $a['message'].' '.$a['description'][0]['STORECODE'].' '.$a['description'][0]['POSTALCODE'].' '.$a['description'][0]['DCNAME'];
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose data is stored in a variable

```
$data = {"resultcode":"0","message":"Success","description":[{"STORECODE":"F3YQ","STORENAME":"BUNGUR BESAR 30B","ADDRESS":"JL.BUNGUR BESAR NO.30BGUNUNG SAHARI SELATAN","PHONE":"021","POSTALCODE":"10610","OPHOURS":"EVERYDAY (07.00-22.00)","LATITUDE":"-6.1605556","LONGITUDE":"106.8391667","DCCODE":"G137","DCNAME":"JKT2"}]};

$values = json_decode($data);

echo $values['description'][0]['STORECODE'];
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to use `json_decode()` to covert `json` to `array` then you can do what you want Please check below code

```
$str_json = '{"resultcode":"0","message":"Success","description":[{"STORECODE":"F3YQ","STORENAME":"BUNGUR BESAR 30B","ADDRESS":"JL.BUNGUR BESAR NO.30BGUNUNG SAHARI SELATAN","PHONE":"021","POSTALCODE":"10610","OPHOURS":"EVERYDAY (07.00-22.00)","LATITUDE":"-6.1605556","LONGITUDE":"106.8391667","DCCODE":"G137","DCNAME":"JKT2"}]}';
echo'<pre>';print_r(json_decode($str_json,true));
$str_array = json_decode($str_json,true);
echo $str_array['message'].' '.$str_array['description'][0]['STORECODE'].' '.$str_array['description'][0]['POSTALCODE'].' '.$str_array['description'][0]['DCNAME'];die;
```

OUTPUT:

```
Array
(
    [resultcode] => 0
    [message] => Success
    [description] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [STORECODE] => F3YQ
                    [STORENAME] => BUNGUR BESAR 30B
                    [ADDRESS] => JL.BUNGUR BESAR NO.30BGUNUNG SAHARI SELATAN
                    [PHONE] => 021
                    [POSTALCODE] => 10610
                    [OPHOURS] => EVERYDAY (07.00-22.00)
                    [LATITUDE] => -6.1605556
                    [LONGITUDE] => 106.8391667
                    [DCCODE] => G137
                    [DCNAME] => JKT2
                )

        )

)
Success F3YQ 10610 JKT2
```

Answer (score 0):

[Demo Link](https://paiza.io/projects/IFI2uU37JrCDwGrfAebgEA?language=php)

You can get data using **json_decode** php function

```
$nvjsonresponse = '{"resultcode":"0","message":"Success","description":[{"STORECODE":"F3YQ","STORENAME":"BUNGUR BESAR 30B","ADDRESS":"JL.BUNGUR BESAR NO.30BGUNUNG SAHARI SELATAN","PHONE":"021","POSTALCODE":"10610","OPHOURS":"EVERYDAY (07.00-22.00)","LATITUDE":"-6.1605556","LONGITUDE":"106.8391667","DCCODE":"G137","DCNAME":"JKT2"}]};'
$nvarrayval = json_decode($nvjsonresponse,true);
print_r($nvarrayval);
```